# Tkinter canvas scroll bars don't follow frame past a certain point

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to understand the drawing of binary trees.  I found an excellent starter at

http://billmill.org/pymag-trees/

The code provided uses graphic calls that are not part of any python library I recognize, so I have converted the graphics calls to tkinter and have the code running except for one unexpected behavior. When I resize the frame (make it larger) the scroll bars at some point get left behind.  They are not staying with the frame as it re-sizes. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from gen import Tree
from demo_trees import trees
from knuth import layout

r = 30
rh = r*1.5
rw = r*1.5

def drawt(canvas, root, depth):
    canvas.create_oval(root.x * rw, depth * rh, 
                   root.x * rw + r, depth * rh + r, 
                   fill = 'white',
                   width = 2)
    for child in root.children:
        drawt(canvas, child, depth+1)

def drawconn(canvas, root, depth):
    for child in root.children:
        canvas.create_line(root.x * rw + (r/2), depth * rh + (r/2),
         child.x * rw + (r/2), (depth+1) * rh + (r/2),
         width = 2)
        drawconn(canvas, child, depth+1)

def main():

    root = Tk()

    # Create the main frame. The frame will include a 
    # scrollable canvas.
    frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=309, relief=SUNKEN)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Add scroll bars
    xscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)

    yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
    yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

    # Add the canvas
    canvas = Canvas(frame, width=500, height=300,
                scrollregion=(-20, -20, 500, 300),
                xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
                yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    xscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
    yscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

    frame.pack()

    # Now draw the tree
    t = layout(trees[2])
    drawconn(canvas, t, 0)
    drawt(canvas, t, 0)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The drawing is scrolling properly and everything is fine until the frame is resized (larger) Can anyone tell me why the scroll bars are not moving with the frame?

If anyone is interested, the complete tree drawing code is from the above link, and corresponds to the code in figure2.py of the download provided.

Comment: BTW, the graphics code was for [Nodebox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Home). Neat work!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure since I can't run your code due to missing dependencies, but if I had to guess,I'd say that it's because you don't pack the frame such that it will expand and contract. You say the scrollbars "get left behind" but I bet the canvas also has the same problem.

Try modifying the line where you pack the frame to be:

```
frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: I am new here.  I would have gladly to provided dependencies, but there was a fair amount of code involved; too much to put in the posting.  Is there some way to attach a .zip or such to provide complete code?

Comment: @JohnSchroeder: no, there is not.